# How could I prove that $g$ is differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Let $x_1, \dots, x_{k - 1} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be fixed and let $f \colon U \subset \mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ a $k$ times differentiable function. I want to prove that $g \colon U \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ given by $g(z) = D^{k - 1}f(z)\left(x_1, \dots, x_{k - 1}\right)$ is differentiable and that $Dg(z)\left(x_k\right) = D^kf(z)(x_k, x_1, \dots, x_{k - 1})$.

I think the proof I've got has a mistake. Here it is:

$g$ can be written as the composition of
$$D^{k - 1}f \colon U \longrightarrow \mathcal{L}^{k - 1}\left(\mathbb{R}^n; \mathbb{R}^m\right)$$
and
$$\lambda \colon \mathcal{L}^{k - 1}\left(\mathbb{R}^n; \mathbb{R}^m\right) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^m,$$
where $\lambda(T) = T\left(x_1, \dots, x_{k - 1}\right)$. Since $\lambda$ is linear, by the chain rule we can write, for $z \in U$,
$$Dg(z) = D\left(\lambda \circ D^{k - 1}(f)\right)(z) = D\lambda\left(D^{k - 1}f(z)\right) \circ D\left(D^{k - 1}f\right)(z) = \\$$
$$= \lambda \circ D\left[D^{k - 1}f\right](z) \in \mathcal{L}\left(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m\right).$$
Consequently, for $x_k \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $D\left[D^{k - 1}f\right](z)\left(x_k\right) \in \mathcal{L}\left(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathcal{L}^{k - 1}\left(\mathbb{R}^n; \mathbb{R}^m\right)\right) \equiv \mathcal{L}^k\left(\mathbb{R}^n; \mathbb{R}^m\right)$, and we can write
$$Dg(z)\left(x_k\right) = \lambda\left(D\left(D^{k - 1}f\right)(z)\left(x_k\right)\right) = D\left(D^{k - 1}f\right)(z)\left(x_k\right)\left(x_1, \dots, x_{k - 1}\right) = \\$$
$$= D^kf(z)\left(x_k, x_1, \dots, x_{k - 1}\right)$$
(we identify $D(Df)(z)(h)(k)$ with $D^2f(z)(h, k)$).

I don't understand the last equalities. I don't really understand what is $\lambda\left(D\left(D^{k - 1}f\right)(z)\left(x_k\right)\right)$, I mean, is that even defined? $D\left(D^{k - 1}f\right)(z)\left(x_k\right) \in \mathcal{L}^k\left(\mathbb{R}^n; \mathbb{R}^m\right)$, so $\lambda$ shouldn't be defined there. It is really confusing, but could you help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The differential at the point $z\in U$ of $D^{k - 1}f \colon U \longrightarrow \mathcal{L}^{k - 1}\left(\mathbb{R}^n; \mathbb{R}^m\right)$ is
$$D(D^{k-1}f)(z)\in\mathcal L(\Bbb R^n,\mathcal{L}^{k - 1}\left(\mathbb{R}^n; \mathbb{R}^m\right)).$$
If we apply it to the vector $x_k\in\Bbb R^n$, we get
$$T:=D(D^{k-1}f)(z)(x_k)\in\mathcal{L}^{k - 1}\left(\mathbb{R}^n; \mathbb{R}^m\right)$$
and then
$$\begin{align}\lambda(D(D^{k-1}f)(z)(x_k))&=\lambda(T)\\&=T(x_k,x_1,\dots,x_{k-1})\\&=D\left(D^{k - 1}f\right)(z)\left(x_k\right)\left(x_1, \dots, x_{k - 1}\right).
\end{align}$$
By the recursive definition of iterated differentials, this is precisely $D^kf(z)\left(x_k, x_1, \dots, x_{k - 1}\right)$.